# get text file from server with meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I'm trying to develop a simple app and I'd like to read from a changing text file on the server with the meteor framework.

A little background: I tried using straight javascript to read the text file, but I got an error when doing this.  My javascript was the following:

```
$.get("./temp.txt",function(returnedData)
{
$("#element").text(returnedData);
},"text/plain");

var text = $("#element").text();
```

In the web development tools in chromium it says the following when the script is run: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/grneggandsam/WebDevelopment/Test/temp.txt. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource."

Edit: I should say that in firefox it appears to be working fine... not sure why it doesn't work in chromium and chrome...

Sorry - I'm pretty new to pulling data off of servers.  After doing some research on this error I started to think it might be because I am not using a server-side language.  So, I decided to look into the Meteor Framework.  I also just want to learn the meteor framework because of its usefulness.

My question is: Is there a way to read a text file with the Meteor framework, and how do you do it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to achieve this by writing things to a plain .html file and you are not using a webserver?

That's why you are getting this error. As you can see, the error tells you to use one of those protocols for your AJAX-request: `http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource`. You are using the protocol `file`, which is not in the list.

Just to solve this problem, you don't have to learn the whole Meteor framework. I'd recommend that you install a simple HTTP-Server and try to get your script up and running over there.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10752078/2906770) SO-answer. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21608670/2906770) answer over there describes how to get a simple HTTP-Server.